# How to remove last character in request url using apache?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to remove last character(#) in request url using apache.
Example
www.example.com/test/test?data=value1,value2,value3#

how to remove # value in the url.
         (OR)
Make apache to allow #.

Now i am getting 400 response in apache.

Comment: `#` (and anything after it) is not even sent to the apache, there must be something else involved

Comment: This url come from tracking device. If i try to post in browser url # will be removed, but while receiving from device  it prints # in apache access log..@DusanBajic

Answer (score 0):

`#` is reserved character according to [rfc3986 section-2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) and it seems there is no way to make Apache ignore it, it will throw error 400 immediately when it gets the request (even without waiting for headers to arrive).
Your best bet may be to write simple custom reverse proxy that will strip that character before forwarding the request to Apache httpd.